# Excel: Data Processing for Pivot - Extract from Single Column to Multiple

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of values that I need to format for processing and the format of the data isn't suitable in it's current form.

The values are currently in the following format:

[image]

There are far too many records to attempt this manually. What's the best way to automate the process, either with a formula or VBA?

EDIT: The values in C3:C4 appear for each set of records in the sheet. The number of cells below them can vary from 1 to 3,000.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Tim you've been a huge help and I massively appreciate it - the edited version didn't work though for some reason. In any case, I modified it very rudimentarily to loop back through and empty the cell values for the ones I didn't want marked. Thanks again.

```
Sub Tester()

Const STATUS_FLAG As String = "status code:*"

Dim v1, v2
Dim c As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In sht.Range(sht.Range("C1"), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        If c.Value Like STATUS_FLAG Then
            v1 = c.Offset(-2, 0)
            v2 = c.Offset(-1, 0)
        ElseIf c.Value Like "http:*" Then
            c.Offset(0, -2).Value = v1
            c.Offset(0, -1).Value = v2
        End If
        If c.Value Like STATUS_FLAG Then
            c.Offset(-2, -2).Value = ""
            c.Offset(-2, -1).Value = ""
            c.Offset(-1, -2).Value = ""
            c.Offset(-1, -1).Value = ""
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your expected format?

Comment: +1 on @nutsch's comment. Please post a screen shot of the `after` in addition to the `before` and we can help much easier.

Comment: Thanks for asking. The data in it's original format has no values in Col A and B and needs the cell values I've referenced in the respective places. I've used the cell references because the values may have been confusing - I'll post it in two images next time if it helps. I hope that makes it clearer but if not, please tell me.

Comment: You will need VBA for this I think. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: don't fill in next to "source" paths (v1, v2)

```
Sub Tester()

Const STATUS_FLAG As String = "Status code:*"

Dim v1, v2
Dim c As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In sht.Range(sht.Range("C1"), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        If Len(c.Value)=0 Then
            'reset on blank row
            v1=""
            v2=""
        ElseIf c.Value Like STATUS_FLAG Then
            v1 = c.Offset(-2, 0)
            v2 = c.Offset(-1, 0)
        ElseIf c.Value Like "http:*" and Len(v1)>0 Then
            c.Offset(0, -2).Value = v1
            c.Offset(0, -1).Value = v2
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim thank you so much (I made one minor change - 'c.Offset(0, -1).Value = v2' -  but it works brilliantly. I'm not yet confident enough with VBA to write these things quickly so I'd been trying to replicate it with a formula, which was proving difficult.

Comment: It's recording against the URLs that are being pasted but I'm sure I can figure out a way to delete these rows. Thanks again for your help - it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edited my answer to fix that.